# how to edit where facebook sends visitor after using the facebook "sign in" app

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I have a site www.crazyfloridadeals.com and this is a licensed directory and it has a built in feature for "sign in" using your facebook account and in order to do this you need a developers App ID and App secret which I did set up, I got the app to work but two things need to be edited and I can't figure out how to do this,

1. After you use the app facebook sends the visitor to crazyfloridadeals.com/profile/#*=* which 404's how do I get the app to send them back to the Home page? I read every articl and forum but could not find anything - any suggestions are where to find this
2. When you use the facebook app it goues through the "permissions" and it asks do you want to all "my company" to post on your behalf? I don't need this as I am only looking for basic user info (just like screen shot attached) how can I adjust what permissions are being asked for?

I am new to this and am sorry if these are easy fixes

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your site, it appears that the FB login button is being passed the paramaters redirect_uri="http://crazyfloridadeals.com/members/facebookauth.php?destiny=http://crazyfloridadeals.com/profile/#="
and scope="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"

There should be a configuration screen if this is some sort of CMS for the FB login plugin. Otherwise there may be a configuration file somewhere in the code files itself. Of note, to remove the "post on my behalf" message, remove the 'publish_stream' from the scope variable. See [this list](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for other FB permissions. You may need a FB Dev account to view it. Obviously, you will need to change "http://crazyfloridadeals.com/profile/#=" to just "http://crazyfloridadeals.com/"